# How to upload a file from Vertex AI Workbench to AWS S3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have an access in Google Cloud and AWS. I wanted to upload a file from Vertex AI Workbench to AWS S3, is that possible? Or there is an alternative way?

I have read some [tread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47095834/how-to-access-google-cloud-storage-bucket-using-aws-cli) that might help me, and have try some code, but still can't solve my problem, and raise an error

> Could not connect to the endpoint URL:
> "https://xyz.s3.auto.amazonaws.com/uploaded.csv?uploads"

Here is my code

```
import boto3
import os
import io

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

key_id="my_key"
access_key="my_access_key"

client = boto3.client("s3", region_name="auto", aws_access_key_id=key_id, aws_secret_access_key=access_key)

client.upload_file(
    Filename="path_file.csv",
    Bucket="bucket_name",
    Key="uploaded.csv",
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue here is you're using `region=auto` for AWS which is not supported. The region needs to be real [region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.RegionsAndAvailabilityZones.html) because (you can see in the error) it's being used to pick the endpoint.
Try it without that.

```
import os
import io

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

key_id="my_key"
access_key="my_access_key"

client = boto3.client("s3", aws_access_key_id=key_id, aws_secret_access_key=access_key)

client.upload_file(
    Filename="path_file.csv",
    Bucket="bucket_name",
    Key="uploaded.csv",
)
```